# Load fragments on part of the screen only?

Tags: android, tabs

I would like to know if it is possible to type a Tablayout system only on part of the screen. ex:

[image]

Where the green, blue and orange colors would be the Tabs buttons, and the red part would be the Fragment loaded, then clicking each of the buttons (green, blue and orange) would trade Fragment without affecting the rest of the layout. I wonder if this is possible and if so, how would you do it? If it's any other way than being with Fragments, it works.

If anyone has an example, I am grateful.

Comment: You mean TabLayout with ViewPager?

Comment: @user221256 Yes, yes, it could be, but I do not know how to do it, could you give me an example?

Comment: Assuming you know how to use ViewPager with fragments: You will set specific `android:height` attribute value for ex. 120dp. You probably have multiple fragments, each containing their own layout, similarly set the height on the root layout in their layout file. And do everything else the standard way.